# Deleting a URL in Wordpress Using FTP

Tags: wordpress, url, ftp

I am trying to delete a specific URL for a website and cannot seem to locate the file in FTP. There is no public_html folder for the site when I FTP in. Does someone know where I might be able to access the pages?

Comment: What do you mean "delete a URL using FTP"? You can't delete a URL via FTP.

Comment: Are you talking about deleting a page on your WP site?

Answer (score 0):

Remove it via your WP admin login? Not via FTP?

By "URL" do you mean removing one of the webpages? Because you have to do that via your wordpress panel you can't do that by FTP (you can do it via the database tho I believe)

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress is a cms system. You would need to log into the portal. http://yourdomainname.com/wp-admin. There is no actual pages. They are all theme files inside your wordpress theme folder. (httpdocs/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/page.php. Though I don't think the url would be there.)